# Passing fields to a silverlight app from the command line

Tags: html, silverlight, url

Silverlight is made so that you can run it in a browser.  That is cool.  So, if I want to pass variables from the command line so that it can be used to populate fields in the silverlight app, how is that done?

You know, like you can with javascript (I think) or php (I am pretty sure).

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has Init parameters which is a key/value map that you can fill in your Html page and get the values in Application_Startup event. However this does not apply to Silverlight apps running in OOTB (out of the browser) mode.

This MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) shows a trick if you run your app both in and out of browser, so that you can save the InitParams values when running in the browser and save it back to Isolated Storage for when you run the application in OOTB mode.

Comment: It looks like I will have to use XAP file.  How come it is only built in my debug directory and not in my release?